# iOS periodic background work with notifications and rescheduling

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to implement one thing in iOS app, but I have no idea where to start with it and what to use to achieve my desired goal.

Here is what I am looking to do:

Every day at some particular time (let's say 2 a.m.) no matter if application is in foreground or background or closed, it should do the following:

1. Do Http POST request.
2. Receive response and parse it.
3. If response satisfies my needs, a `Notification` should be displayed with some data.
4. If it doesn't satisfy my needs, do nothing.

The questions are:

1. What should I look into for this kind of background task?
2. How do I display Notifications?

Comment: Look into BackgroudTasks and UserNotifications frameworks

Comment: @cora will `BackgroundTasks` work even when the application is killed?

Comment: No. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623111-applicationwillterminate

Comment: @cora you say no, but the doc you linked says this: For apps that support background execution, this method is generally not called when the user quits the app because the app simply moves to the background in that case. However, this method may be called in situations where the app is running in the background (not suspended) and the system needs to terminate it for some reason. ---- which if I understand correctly, means that if app has `background processing` is not killed in most situations and is simply moved to background

Comment: Best is to re evaluate your approach: instead of client fetching data, and issuing local notification, make _server side_ do verification and issue remote notification to the client if the result "satisfies your needs". This way you don't need whole bunch of additional permissions (such as background fetch), don't consume battery, and don't face other issues with scheduling and so on

Comment: @KirilS. What you are suggesting sounds perfectly logical and is the way I am going to do this. My initial idea to do it this way was because I already introduced such behavior on Android and it is working perfectly fine, but after doing some research I came to conclusion that there is no 100% sure way to do the same thing on iOS so I will resort to server-side instead. Thank you